What's the difference between resolve, resolution, and determination?
I got some results after researching, that "resolve" is the determination on a stronger level than "resolution" this link .
But I haven't figured out the difference between "determination" and the two other words despite some forums' explanations. this link
So in which context is each of these 3 words used?

Generally "determination" suggests will, or willpower, and "resolve" suggests a decision. Therefore, there are situations where only "resolve" can be used. Like new years resolutions; "This year I resolve to work harder".

...well, that's what someone else says. Me, I think often the two words are semantically equivalent, but syntactically different, so it has to be This year I am determined to work harder for the previous example. And in some contexts, resolve actually means solve, fix, successfully deal with, so if you've resolved the problem you no longer have a problem, whereas if you've determined the problem that just means you've figured out exactly what the problem actually is (so now you can get on and resolve it! :)

Determination can have a shade of meaning that resolution does not.  It can mean "grit", i.e. the mental fortitude to continue toward one's goal when facing adversity or multiple obstacles along the way.
resolve can be used to express that meaning too if you add an intensifying adjective:

Even as they were suffering from its debilitating effects, they showed great resolve in their efforts to pass a law that would make experimental therapies available to those who had the fatal disease.

But if you turn resolution into an adjective, resolute, you can express that meaning though perhaps a little less forcefully:

Even as they were suffering from its debilitating effects, they were resolute in their efforts to pass a law that would make experimental therapies available to those who had the fatal disease.


So to sum up, resolution has the least strong level of the 3 words. (As I read from some source, it means a decision to do or not to do something).
Resolve and determination show a strong sense of commitment, and resolve often goes with an intensifying adjective.
Am I right?

That's a fair summary, except that the right adjective can often put a lot of spin on an abstract noun.  For example, "They showed unflagging resolution in  their efforts..."  or "tireless resolution".  But these are formulaic phrases that are somewhat oratorical.
